# How can I add lists and similar in a savebox?

Tags: lists, boxes

I'd like to have a savebox (or savebox-like functionality) that contains some 'simple' formatting, for example lists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  This is a sentence
  \begin{itemize}
    \item I am a list
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

However my experimenting with `\savebox`, `\sbox`, `\begin{savebox}` and the like are failing me. I also tried to define a `minipage` inside the savebox, but either that doesn't work or I don't know the syntax.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\newcommand{\reptext}{This ...}` and then `\reptext` when you need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this type of material you can just save your text etc. in a macro

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mytext}{This is a sentence
\begin{itemize}
\item I am a list
\end{itemize}}

\mytext

Something else.

\mytext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

While Andrew's solution works great in many, many situations, it will fail in some, for example, if you try to place `\mytext` in an `\fbox`.  To get around that problem, you really have to define `\mytext` to place the contents in a box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent 0in
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mytext}{\setbox0=\vbox{%
This is a sentence
\begin{itemize}
\item I am a list
\end{itemize}%
}\box0}

\mytext

Something else.

{\hfill\makebox[0pt]{\fbox{\mytext}}\hfill}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you think that `\fbox{\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}}` is legal? I bet you don't. So what? Of course you get an overfull message with your code and adding `\noindent` won't help.

Comment: @egreg I was just trying to make the more general point that there are some things that actually have to get stuffed into a box if you are going to later manipulate them.  Perhaps this was not the best example on which to make that point.

Comment: @egreg Revised my MWE to better make the point.