# Put a box around an item (homework)

Tags: lists, enumerate, framed

I am using the `enumerate` environment to do homework. In the following, first I write out the question, then I write out the answers to the first two parts.

What I'd like to do is have a box around the question. How can I do that?

I tried using `tikzmark` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33443/box-around-single-element-in-list) but it did not work (the box shows up in the wrong place when I try to use math mode. See the code at the end of the article

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item[1.]
    Consider the initial value problem 
    \[
     \frac{dy}{dx} = 1- (y-x)^2, \qquad y=0 \,\, \text{at} \,\, x=0
    \]
    \begin{enumerate}
     \item[(a)] Find a solution to the problem.
     \item[(b)] Regardless of (a), is the solution unique?
     \item[(c)] Write down the Picard iteration scheme for this ODE and find some $r>0$ for which it converges $|x|<r$.
     \item[(d)] Find some $R>0$ such that the Picard iterates \textit{diverge} for $|x|>R$. 


    \end{enumerate}

    \item[1a.]
       $\phi(x) = x$ is a solution, since $$\phi'(x) = 1 = 1 - (x-x)^2.$$

    \item[1b.]
       Note that the function $1-(y-x)^2$ is $C^{\infty}$ in both $x$ and $y$, and therefore given $x_0$, the function is locally Lipschitz in $y$, uniformly with respect to $x$ for $x$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$. Therefore such a solution is unique.
     \end{enumerate}
     \end{document}
```

Using the `tikzmark` idea (didn't work)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\tikzmark{bl} 1.]
Consider the initial value problem 
\[
 \frac{dy}{dx} = 1- (y-x)^2, \qquad y=0 \,\, \text{at} \,\, x=0
\]
\begin{enumerate}
 \item[(a)] Find a solution to the problem.
 \item[(b)] Regardless of (a), is the solution unique?
 \item[(c)] Write down the Picard iteration scheme for this ODE and find some $r>0$ for which it converges $|x|<r$.
 \item[(d)] Find some $R>0$ such that the Picard iterates \textit{diverge} for $|x|>R$. 
\end{enumerate}
\tikzmark{br}
\item[2.] Something not boxed
\item[3.] Also not boxed.
\end{enumerate}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[red]
  ($(bl)+(-0.2em,0.9em)$) rectangle
  ($(br)+(0.2em,-0.3em)$);}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** A problem came when I tried to apply the suggestion given below. `tikzmark` always wants to put the box on the last page. So if the document is only one page, it is fine. But if it jumps to two pages, it is wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\leavevmode
\strut
\vadjust{%%
  \noindent
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\ht\strutbox+1ex}[0pt][0pt]{\tikzmark{bl}}}%%
Consider the initial value problem 
\[
  \frac{dy}{dx} = 1- (y-x)^2, \qquad y=0 \,\, \text{at} \,\, x=0
\]
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item Find a solution to the problem.
   \item Regardless of (a), is the solution unique?
   \item Write down the Picard iteration scheme for this ODE and find some $r>0$ for which it converges $|x|<r$.
   \item Find some $R>0$ such that the Picard iterates \textit{diverge} for $|x|>R$. 
  \end{enumerate}

\leavevmode
\vadjust{%
  \noindent
  \hspace*{\dimexpr\textwidth+1ex}\tikzmark{br}}%%

  \item[1a.]
   $\phi(x) = x$ is a solution, since $$\phi'(x) = 1 = 1 - (x-x)^2.$$

\item[1b.]
   Note that the function $1-(y-x)^2$ is $C^{\infty}$ in both $x$ and $y$, and therefore given $x_0$, the function is locally Lipschitz in $y$, uniformly with respect to $x$ for $x$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$. Therefore such a solution is unique.

   \item[1c.]
    For convenience of notation, let us agree to label the constant function $0$ as the first Picard iterate $y_1(x)$ rather than the $0$th Picard iterate.
 \begin{align*}
  y_2(x) &= \int_0^x 1 - (y_1 - \xi)^2 d\xi = x - \frac13 x^3 \\
  y_3(x) &= \int_0^x 1 - (y_2(\xi) - \xi)^2 d\xi = \int_0^x 1 - \left(\frac13 \xi^3\right)^2 d\xi = x - \frac{1}{7\cdot 3^2}x^7 \\
  y_4(x) &= \dotsb = x - \frac{1}{15\cdot 7^2 \cdot 3^4}x^{15}\\
  \vdots \\
  y_n(x) &= x - \frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{n} (2^k-1)^{2^{(n-k)}}} x^{2^n - 1}
 \end{align*}
 The iterates will converge pointwise for $|x|<1$ (making no claim that that is the largest such interval). Since the modulus of the second term of $y_n$ is increasing with the modulus of $x$, we can say that the iterates will converge uniformly on compact subsets of the unit interval. (Given $[-a, a]\subseteq (-1,1)$, pick $n$ such that the second term of $y_n(a)$ is less than $\epsilon$; then this $n$ will work for all $x \in [-a, a]$.)

\item[1d.]
 Suppose we find an $x$ for which 
 \begin{align*}
  x-\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{n} (2^k-1)^{2^{(n-k)}}} x^{2^n - 1}
  \end{align*}
 diverges to infinity (of course it will diverge iff the second term diverges). Then by the same considerations as in part (c), we can say that it will diverge for $\xi$ such that $|\xi| > |x|$.  

 Suppose we choose $x=4$. We have 

 \[
 y_n(x) = 4 - \frac{2^{2(2^n-1)}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n} (2^k-1)^{2^{(n-k)}}}.
 \]
 Note that the denominator satisfies
 \[
  (2^n-1)^{2^0}(2^{n-1}-1)^{2^1}\dotsb (2^2-1)^{2^{n-2}}\leq 2^{n2^0 + (n-1)2^1 + \dotsb + (2)2^{n-2}},
 \]
 where we have left out the final factor because it is equal to one. Some algebra tells us that $n2^0 + (n-1)2^1 + \dotsb + (2)2^{n-2} = 2^{n}+2^{n-1}-(n+2)\leq 2^{n+1}-(n+2)$. When we consider 
 \[
  \frac{2^{2(2^n-1)}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n} (2^k-1)^{2^{(n-k)}}} \geq \frac{C2^{2^{n+1}}}{2^{2^{n+1}-(n+2)}}=C2^{n+2},
 \]
 this clearly diverges.

 \item[2.] Let $y=\phi(x)$ and $y=\psi(x)$ be linearly independent solutions of the ODE $y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0$, where $p$ and $q$ are continuous on an open interval $I$. Prove the following statements:
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item[(a)] Suppose that $x_0 \in I$ is a zero of $\phi$, then $\psi$ cannot have a relative extremum value at $x_0$.
 \item[(b)] Suppose that $x_0$ and $x_1$ are two consecutive zeros of $\phi$ in $I$. Then $\psi$ must have a zero at some $\xi$, $x_0<\xi<x_1$.

 \end{enumerate}

[\textit{Hint:} Think Wronskian.]

\end{enumerate}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[red]
  (bl) rectangle
  (br);}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't put the question in the enumerate environment in the first place, especially since you are manually numbering these 'items'.  If you want something that relies on TikZ, I recommend `tcolorbox`.

Comment: You'd put it in its own enumerate environment?

Comment: You should apply the overlay as soon as you have finished marking the bounds of the box.  Don't wait until later, `tikz` may remember the dimensions, but it doesn't necessarily remember the page it was defined on.

Comment: Also, using `$$...$$` for displayed math is deprecated, use `\[...\]` or one of the environments provided by the AMS packages.

Comment: A few considerations: you should apply different "names" for each marker, otherwise only the last is remembered (likely the one at the bottom of the page). Second, there are a few versions of `\tikzmark`: one makes use of customizable offsets. Have a look to [Enumerated text and formula with background color](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69158/13304) for a demo. However, for this I would also use `tcolorbox`.

Comment: You should check out the `exam` class and it's `solution` environment.

Comment: I suppose I would've created my own numbered environment in a `tcolorbox`; now that there are several answers here, I'd probably pick whichever of the below answers seemed to best abstract form from content.  (One thing I still recommend, though, is to not manually number your lists.)

Comment: @SeanAllred That's really helpful. The only thing is: when I do homework, usually the questions will be short and the answers long. Therefore it makes more sense to have the answers unboxed and the questions boxed. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this in `exam`...do you know one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my answer at [How can I add lists and similar in a savebox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169347/how-can-i-add-lists-and-similar-in-a-savebox/169357#169357), I placed the question in a temporary vbox, and then embraced it in an `\fbox`, making the appropriate allowances for indentation.

I here define the process as a macro, `\boxitem{}`:

```
\def\boxitem#1{\setbox0=\vbox{#1}{\centering\makebox[0pt]{%
  \fboxrule=2pt\color{red}\fbox{\hspace{\leftmargini}\color{black}\box0}}\par}}
```

And then use it inside the `enumerate` as `\boxitem{\item[]...}`.  Note: `\boxitem` was REVISED to make it insensitive to succeeding blank lines.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath, xcolor}% ADDED xcolor
\def\boxitem#1{\setbox0=\vbox{#1}{\centering\makebox[0pt]{%
  \fboxrule=2pt\color{red}\fbox{\hspace{\leftmargini}\color{black}\box0}}\par}}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
\boxitem{% THIS LINE ADDED
    \item[1.]
    Consider the initial value problem 
    \[
     \frac{dy}{dx} = 1- (y-x)^2, \qquad y=0 \,\, \text{at} \,\, x=0
    \]
    \begin{enumerate}
     \item[(a)] Find a solution to the problem.
     \item[(b)] Regardless of (a), is the solution unique?
     \item[(c)] Write down the Picard iteration scheme for this ODE and find some $r>0$ for which it converges $|x|<r$.
     \item[(d)] Find some $R>0$ such that the Picard iterates \textit{diverge} for $|x|>R$. 
    \end{enumerate}
}% THIS LINE ADDED
    \item[1a.]
       $\phi(x) = x$ is a solution, since $$\phi'(x) = 1 = 1 - (x-x)^2.$$
    \item[1b.]
       Note that the function $1-(y-x)^2$ is $C^{\infty}$ in both $x$ and $y$, and therefore given $x_0$, the function is locally Lipschitz in $y$, uniformly with respect to $x$ for $x$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$. Therefore such a solution is unique.
     \end{enumerate}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

POSTSCRIPT: From my exchange with the OP in the comments, I will just add that if one wanted to add a fixed vertical space before and after my `\fbox`, the definition of `\boxitem` could be defined as follows, where a space of `3ex` is added, by way of example.

```
\def\boxitem#1{\vspace{3ex}\setbox0=\vbox{#1}{\centering\makebox[0pt]{%
  \fboxrule=2pt\color{red}\fbox{\hspace{\leftmargini}\color{black}\box0}}\vspace{3ex}\par}}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer here so far, so thank you. I'm  having a little trouble; see "edit 2" to my question.

Comment: @EricAuld Remove the blank line after the closing brace of `\boxitem`  The influence of `\hfil` and `\hfill` are dependent on what precedes and follows.  I'll see if I can make it less sensitive to blank lines.

Comment: @EricAuld See revised definition of `\boxitem`, which now uses `\centering` and `\par` instead of `\hfil` and `\hfill`.

Comment: If I wanted to modify the macro to add some `vspace` before and after the boxed item, where would I place that command in the macro?

Comment: @EricAuld You can add `\vspace{3ex}`, for example, right before the `\par` at the end of the `\boxitem` definition.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see `\par` anywhere in the definition above. Am I missing something?

Comment: in my revised answer, I define `\def\boxitem#1{\setbox0=\vbox{#1}{\centering\makebox[0pt]{\fboxrule=2pt\color{red}\fbox{\hspace{\leftmargini}\color{black}\box0}}\vspace{3ex}\par}}`.  The `\par` occurs at the end.  I show here where the `\vspace` would go.

Comment: Thanks! Where would I put the `\vspace` command for space before the box? I tried before the `\fbox` command, and right after the first #1, but neither worked.

Comment: @EricAuld For leading space, place the `\vspace` at the very beginning of the definition, right before the `\setbox`.

Comment: Thanks! Wish I could upvote this answer a few more times.

Comment: @EricAuld One upvote is sufficient, but you may want to revise your question to remove Edit 2, since we have resolved the issue.  And thank you.

Comment: @EricAuld One last thought... unlike some of the other solutions, mine will not split across a page boundary.  It is something for you to think about.

Comment: OK. Good tip. --

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I am using this code in double column page. But the problem is that the box has slightly more width than the single column. How can i manage width?

Comment: @Infinity  The length `\fboxsep` governs the gap size between the text and the box, while the length `\fboxrule` governs the thickness of the box rule.  Does this help?

Comment: @Infinity  While my macro changes `\fboxrule`, the default value of `\fboxsep` is used.  But you can change it.

Answer (score 13):

As was mentioned in the comments, you can also use the `tcolorbox`  package for creating the box. In my example code, I took over the `enumitem` package suggestion of A.Ellett.

The code uses your example three times: without box, with box, and finally with a box broken from one page to the following.

Color, line width, arcs etc. of the box can be adapted.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw,breakable,pad at break=1mm,
  oversize,left=8mm,interior hidden,colframe=red,nobeforeafter=,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
\item
Consider the initial value problem
\[
  \frac{dy}{dx} = 1- (y-x)^2, \qquad y=0 \,\, \text{at} \,\, x=0
\]
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
   \item Find a solution to the problem.\label{finding a solution}
   \item Regardless of \ref{finding a solution}, is the solution unique?
   \item Write down the Picard iteration scheme for this ODE and find some $r>0$ for which it converges $|x|<r$.
   \item Find some $R>0$ such that the Picard iterates \textit{diverge} for $|x|>R$.
  \end{enumerate}
\item Something not boxed
\item Also not boxed.
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
\begin{mybox}
\item Consider the initial value problem
\[
  \frac{dy}{dx} = 1- (y-x)^2, \qquad y=0 \,\, \text{at} \,\, x=0
\]
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
   \item Find a solution to the problem.\label{finding a solution}
   \item Regardless of \ref{finding a solution}, is the solution unique?
   \item Write down the Picard iteration scheme for this ODE and find some $r>0$ for which it converges $|x|<r$.
   \item Find some $R>0$ such that the Picard iterates \textit{diverge} for $|x|>R$.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{mybox}
\item Something not boxed
\item Also not boxed.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
\begin{mybox}
\item Consider the initial value problem
\[
  \frac{dy}{dx} = 1- (y-x)^2, \qquad y=0 \,\, \text{at} \,\, x=0
\]
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
   \item Find a solution to the problem.\label{finding a solution}
   \item Regardless of \ref{finding a solution}, is the solution unique?
   \item Write down the Picard iteration scheme for this ODE and find some $r>0$ for which it converges $|x|<r$.
   \item Find some $R>0$ such that the Picard iterates \textit{diverge} for $|x|>R$.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{mybox}
\item Something not boxed
\item Also not boxed.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like this idea! Your code is not compiling for me (I tried two editors). I get the following error: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/enhanced jigsaw' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Comment: @EricAuld sounds like an update is in order: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: @EricAuld I'm quite sure that @cmhughes is right and the compilation error is caused by an outdated version. The `enhanced jigsaw` key was introduced with `version 2.60 (2013/12/17)`. The current version is `2.80 (2014/03/31)`. Let me know, if you have problems after updating.

Answer (score 3):

This is one possible solution, where the second `\tikzmark{br}` is moved inside the enumerate environment to prevent extra white space. Also the relative distance is adjusted to 5em to cover the whole text.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\tikzmark{bl} 1.]
Consider the initial value problem 
\[
 \frac{dy}{dx} = 1- (y-x)^2, \qquad y=0 \,\, \text{at} \,\, x=0
\]
\begin{enumerate}
 \item[(a)] Find a solution to the problem.
 \item[(b)] Regardless of (a), is the solution unique?
 \item[(c)] Write down the Picard iteration scheme for this ODE and find some $r>0$ for which it converges $|x|<r$.
 \item[(d)] Find some $R>0$ such that the Picard iterates \textit{diverge} for $|x|>R$. \tikzmark{br}
\end{enumerate}

\item[2.] Something not boxed
\item[3.] Also not boxed.
\end{enumerate}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[red]
  ($(bl)+(-0.2em,0.9em)$) rectangle
  ($(br)+(5em,-0.3em)$);}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would make a number of changes:

1. I would use the `enumitem` package to facilitate formatting the labels for your enumerate environments.
2. I would use a `\label/\ref` pair to refer to a previous label

Here's a solution for you box using `tikz` and a `\vadjust`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}%%[inline]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
\item
\leavevmode
\strut
\vadjust{%%
  \noindent
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\ht\strutbox+1ex}[0pt][0pt]{\tikzmark{bl}}}%%
Consider the initial value problem 
\[
  \frac{dy}{dx} = 1- (y-x)^2, \qquad y=0 \,\, \text{at} \,\, x=0
\]
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
   \item Find a solution to the problem.\label{finding a solution}
   \item Regardless of \ref{finding a solution}, is the solution unique?
   \item Write down the Picard iteration scheme for this ODE and find some $r>0$ for which it converges $|x|<r$.
   \item Find some $R>0$ such that the Picard iterates \textit{diverge} for $|x|>R$. 
  \end{enumerate}

\leavevmode
\vadjust{%
  \noindent
  \hspace*{\dimexpr\textwidth+1ex}\tikzmark{br}}%%
\item Something not boxed
\item Also not boxed.
\end{enumerate}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[red]
  (bl) rectangle
  (br);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additionally, I wouldn't use the `enumerate` environment for numbering homework problems.  I would create my own counter and command to do this along the following lines:

```
\newcounter{myproblemcnt}
\newcommand\problem{\par\refstepcounter{myproblemcnt}%%
  \noindent
  \textbf{\arabic{myproblemcnt}.}\hspace*{0.25em}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm coming up against a problem...see the edit.

Comment: Interesting...why wouldn't you use `enumerate`? (I assume you mean for both the problems and the solutions?)

Comment: @EricAuld in the long run I find it makes things easier to manage or reformat.  Also, problems can be numbered independently of other structures like sections and chapters, which may or may not be desirable.  I don't believe that would be possible with an enumerate environment.  Currently, you may feel you don't need to worry about such things, but in the long run it's best to adopt practices that won't later give you headaches.

Comment: Good tip. Say, would there be a problem in defining a `newcommand` macro for the entire `tikz` and `vadjust` sequence you just defined? Something like `\problem`?