# How to enumerate with borders (boxes)?

Tags: enumerate, border

### How to achieve the following using enumeration?

[image]

The wordaround is given below:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, lipsum}
\oddsidemargin 0in \evensidemargin 0in \topmargin 0in \textheight 9.2in  \textwidth 6.5in
\begin{document}


\hrule 
\begin{enumerate}
\item[]
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
Date of Start of Project: XXXX XXXX
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
Total Cost of Project :
XXXXXXXXXX
\end{minipage}\\
\hrule 
\item Methodology:

As in any area of research in Mathematics, the research is exploratory in nature. However, we shall evolve group interaction with many eminent professors nationally and internationally known.\\
\hrule 

\item Salient Research Achievements: \label{salient}\\
\textbf{First Year:  2015-2016}\\
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[label=\ref{salient}.\arabic*]
\item Summary of Achievements.\label{sum_acheive}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\ref{sum_acheive}.\arabic*]
\item   \lipsum[1-2]

\item       \lipsum[3-5]
\end{enumerate}



\end{enumerate}


\end{enumerate}






\hrule


\end{document}
```

The things required:

1. Borders like in the word document.
2. In each page, the border should be like in the word document (which I have added above).
3. So, enumerate should act as a `longtable` environment (note that I don't want to use the `longtable` environment to achieve this).

Comment: You might try with the `framed` environment, but you would have to add  the horizontal lines inside the frame by hand.

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169483/put-a-box-around-an-item-homework

Comment: Your MWE does not compile...by a long shot.

Comment: Kindly let me know what is that framed environment.@Bernard